# Problema al guardar un dato de combo box de Visual Basic en base de datos SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Buenos dias, estoy realizando una inserción desde Visual Basic en una base de datos de SQL Server desde un `ComboBox` que estoy llenando desde una base de datos, a la hora de guardar el dato, en la base de datos me gurda lo siguiente:

lo tengo en clases

Insertar quejas

```
Function Insertar_Queja(ByVal CLIENTE As String, ByVal DIRECCION As String, ByVal CONTACTO As String,
                  ByVal VENDEDOR As String, ByVal FECHA As Date, ByVal OBSERVACIONES As String, ByVal NOTCREDITO As String) As String

    Dim salida As String = "Se genero el Reclamo"
    Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Sp_InsertarQUeja", cn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        With cmd.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@Cliente", CLIENTE)
            .AddWithValue("@DIreccion", DIRECCION)
            .AddWithValue("@Contacto", CONTACTO)
            .AddWithValue("@Vendedor", VENDEDOR)
            .AddWithValue("@Fecha", FECHA)
            .AddWithValue("@Observaciones", OBSERVACIONES)
            .AddWithValue("@Nota_Credito", NOTCREDITO)
        End With
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        salida = "No se genero debido a: " + ex.ToString
    End Try
    Return salida
End Function
```

y en el botón tengo lo siguiente:

```
    MsgBox(conn.Insertar_Queja(CmbCliente.SelectedItem.ToString, TxtDireccion.Text, TxtContacto.Text, CmbVendedor.SelectedItem.ToString, CDate(Dtp1.Text), TxtObservaciones.Text, CmbNotaCredito.SelectedItem.ToString))
```

Todo llamado de este store procedure:

```
@Cliente as varchar (50),
@Direccion as varchar (50),
@Contacto as varchar (50),
@Vendedor as varchar(50),
@Fecha as date,
@Observaciones as varchar(500),
@Nota_Credito as varchar(50)

as

insert RECLAMOS
(Cliente,Direccion,Contacto,Vendedor,Fecha,Observaciones,Nota_Credito)
values
(@Cliente,@Direccion,@Contacto,@Vendedor,@Fecha,@Observaciones,@Nota_Credito)
```

Comment: Buenos días, primero que todo has hecho debug de la aplicación, poniendo un punto de interrupción para poder ver el valor del SelectedItem? estás trabajando en Web o en escritorio? Además podrías agregar más del código,

Comment: Por favor agrega el código que estás usando para que te puedan ayudar a encontrar una solución óptima, lee [ask] para tener mejores bases sobre como formular una buena pregunta

Comment: Es normal que te haga eso. `CmbCliente.SelectedItem` es un `DataRow`, con sus columnas. El método `ToString` de un `DataRow` simplemente te devuelve un string con el nombre de la clase. Pulsa en [edit] y añade exactamente el código que estas usando para guardar en la base de datos y asi poder darte la solución exacta.

Comment: Listo ya esta colocado el código muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CmbCliente.SelectedItem` es un tu caso un `DataRowView`, aunque solo tenga una columna. El método `ToString` de un `DataRowView` simplemente te devuelve un `string` con el nombre de la clase.

En tu caso, hay al menos dos opciones para obtener ese dato:

1.- Usar `SelectedValue` en lugar de `SelectedItem`. Si al cargar los datos en tu `ComboBox` has establecido correctamente la propiedad `ValueMember`, ahi tendrás el valor del campo seleccionado:

```
MsgBox(conn.Insertar_Queja(CmbCliente.SelectedValue.ToString, TxtDireccion.Text, TxtContacto.Text, CmbVendedor.SelectedItem.ToString, CDate(Dtp1.Text), TxtObservaciones.Text, CmbNotaCredito.SelectedItem.ToString))
```

2.- Hacer un *cast* del `SelectedItem` a su autentico tipo (`DataRowView` en tu caso) y obtener el valor de la columna que te interesa dentro del item seleccionado:

```
MsgBox(conn.Insertar_Queja(((DataRowView)CmbCliente.SelectedItem)[0].ToString(), TxtDireccion.Text, TxtContacto.Text, CmbVendedor.SelectedItem.ToString, CDate(Dtp1.Text), TxtObservaciones.Text, CmbNotaCredito.SelectedItem.ToString))
```

o por nombre de columna:

```
MsgBox(conn.Insertar_Queja(((DataRowView)CmbCliente.SelectedItem)["nombreColumna"].ToString(), TxtDireccion.Text, TxtContacto.Text, CmbVendedor.SelectedItem.ToString, CDate(Dtp1.Text), TxtObservaciones.Text, CmbNotaCredito.SelectedItem.ToString))
```